# how to write equation in double column?

Tags: equations, two-column, multicolumn, vspace

I created two columns in LaTeX. But the equations are overflowing from the column. How can I fit the equation into a single column?

```
\begin{multline}
    C(x,y,z,t) = \frac{ (\pi t)^{-3/2} m_T}{8  (K_x K_y K_z)^{1/2}} \text{e}\left(-\frac{(x - 
    x_T - u_x t)^2}{4K_xt} - \frac{(y - y_T - u_y t)^2}{4K_yt} \right) \\ \times \left[ 
    \text{e}\left(-\frac{(z - z_T)^2}{4K_zt}\right) + \text{e} \left( - \frac{(z + z_T)^2} 
    {4K_zt} \right) \right],
    \label{atm_disp_eu}
\end{multline}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fit an equation in a single column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254061/fit-an-equation-in-a-single-column)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you split the equation across *three* lines. I would also suggest you employ `\exp` notation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block
\begin{multline} \label{atm_disp_eu}
C(x,y,z,t) 
    = \frac{ (\pi t)^{-3/2} m_T}{8  (K_x K_y K_z)^{1/2}}\\
    \times 
    \exp\left(-\frac{(x - x_T - u_x t)^2}{4K_xt} 
              -\frac{(y - y_T - u_y t)^2}{4K_yt} \right) \\
    \times 
    \left[
    \exp\left(-\frac{(z - z_T)^2}{4K_zt} \right) + 
    \exp\left(-\frac{(z + z_T)^2}{4K_zt} \right) 
    \right]\,.
\end{multline}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there any other way instead of dividing the equation?

Comment: @YangYung - There might be another way, but it'll likely depend strongly on the document class that's in use. So, do please reveal which document class you employ and if you use a non-default font size.